# Criar tabela sem border

Tags: html, table

É possível criar uma tabela em HTML5 sem as linhas de contorno a preto ou mudar a cor da linha para branco.

```
 <center><table width="500px" height="600px">
 <tr >
 <td>
 <iframe   ></iframe>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <iframe  ></iframe>
 </td>
 </tr>
  </table></center>
```

Já tentei colocar o `Bordercolor`.

Comment: -1, apenas por não apresentar esforço de pesquisa

Comment: Reverti sua edição pois você alterou completamente a pergunta. Poste uma pergunta separada sobre como afetar somente os elementos desejados com CSS.

Comment: quer que faça uma nova pergunta? Ou continuo com esta?

Comment: Faça uma nova. Ou faça uma pesquisa sobre o básico do CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <table border="0">
```

Ou no CSS:

```
table {
    border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

É bem simples, existe um atributo para isto (você precisa procurar por documentações para ver tudo o que existe em cada elemento) embora seja recomendado não usá-lo mais. Vou usar um exemplo que usa o atributo para seguir o estilo que você está usando, mas seu HTML está bem fora do que se usa hoje em dia. *tags*  como `<center>` não devem ser usadas também, o uso de `<iframe>` que também deve ser evitado parece estar sendo usado de forma abusiva também. Outro problema é que algo me diz que você está usando a *tag* para compor *layout* quando ela foi feita apenas para criar tabelas como o próprio nome diz.

```
<table border=0>
```

[Documentação da `<table>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table).

Note que o mesmo pode ser obtido de forma mais apropriada com CSS:

```css
#tabela {
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<table id="tabela">
    <tr>
        <td>
            texto1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            texto2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/TableBorderless.js).

Comment: Espero sinceramente que ele escute esses seus conselhos.

Comment: Alguma coisa me diz que ele nem leu a resposta. QUando se acha o `bordercolor` e não o `border`, deve ser difícil achar achar uma resposta que foi postada depois :)

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria uma classe CSS:

```
.table{border:none;}
```

Comment: Se preferir que todas as tabelas sejam com border:nome; eh so declarar table sem o "." Pois ele deixara de ser classe.. Uma analogia seria dizer que seria tipo uma constante em linguagem de programação ..

Comment: Tomaz, acho que essa resposta fica melhor na outra pergunta que o mesmo usuário acabou de fazer. Essa ele tinha alterado e eu desfiz, pois invalidou as duas respostas que já existiam.

Comment: ok, primeiramente estava digitando de um dispositivo mobile, por isso que obviamente não é nome e sim none. e sim eu utilizo uma classe pra isso, pq cada um tem sua maneira de fazer o serviço, é uma questao de escolha da pessoa