# 2 tabelas diferentes uma da outra

Tags: html, css, table

Quero criar duas tabelas na mesma página só que uma terá bordas e outra não. 
Tenho uma já criada no CSS mas agora não consigo criar outra diferente.

```
 <table border="0" width="500px" height="1000px">
 <tr >
 <td>
  <iframe src=".PDF"   ></iframe>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <iframe src=".PDF"  ></iframe>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table></center>
```

Está tabela fica-me igual a outra. Como consigo contornar isto?

CSS tabela 1 (Construída):

```
table {
    width: 100%;
        }

    table.default {
        width: 100%;
                }

        table.default tbody tr {
            border-bottom: solid 1px #e0e0e0;
        }

        table.default td {
            padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
        }

        table.default th {
            font-weight: 600;
            padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
            text-align: left;
        }

        table.default thead {
            background-color: #555555;
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.15)), url("images/bg01.png");
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.15)), url("images/bg01.png");
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.15)), url("images/bg01.png");
            background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.15)), url("images/bg01.png");
            background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.15)), url("images/bg01.png");
            color: #fff;
        }
```

PS: Agora quero criar um CSS novo para a tabela que coloquei em cima

Comment: Como assim você já tem a tabela criada no css? Você só colocou html aí. O que você tentou fazer até agora na outra tabela?

Comment: Tem certeza que esse CSS foi feito para essa tabela? Há uma classe `.default` e dois seletores `thead` e `tbody` que não estão sendo usados na `table`. Outro ponto é que no HTML a tabela está com CSS *inline* `width:500px` e no CSS esse valor é alterado `width:100%`.

Comment: Esse CSS Foi feito para outra tabela e agora quero criar um CSS novo

Comment: Amigo, procure por tutoriais de css, principalmente sobre os seletores. Parece que você ainda não entendeu como os seletores css funcionam. [Aqui tem um bom tutorial sobre isso](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/sintaxetut.php).

Comment: Dica: width=500px também não existe, px é usado em CSS e não em atributos html. :)

Comment: @ChrisAdler consegue aceitar alguma resposta?

Comment: Retira `.default` é não necessário, coloca o nome classe de elemento mais simples `class="minhatabela"`, ai funciona normal.

Answer (score 6):

Na [resposta sobre a borda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/47704/101) eu dei uma exemplo que resolve o seu problema.

A questão é que usando estilo em `table` você aplica para todas as tabelas. Aplicando estilos em um `id`, você decide em quais tabelas quer aplicar.

Ainda é possível aplicar em `class`, assim você pode aplicar em um grupo de tabelas.

Isto vale para qualquer elemento do HTML, não só tabelas. Procure entender todos os aspectos do HTML e CSS e todas sua relações. Evite usar CSS prontos que você não sabe para que serve.

```css
#tabela1 {
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 600px;
}
#tabela2 {
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<table id="tabela1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            texto1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            texto2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="tabela2">
    <tr>
        <td>
            texto1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            texto2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/TableBorderless2.js).

Tutoriais para lhe ajudar:

- http://pt-br.html.net/tutorials/css/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Getting_Started
- http://www.codecademy.com/pt-BR/tracks/web
- http://pt-br.learnlayout.com/
- http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/layout-css-passo-a-passo.php
- http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/011/firstcss.en.html
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/

Answer (score 2):

Utilize seletores para distinguir as tabelas que a sua página tiver.

```css
p {
  color: red
}

#p {
  color: blue
}

.p {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<p>Selecionado por elemento</p>
<p id='p'>Selecionado por ID</p>
<p class='p'>Selecionado por classe</p>
```

```css
table {
  margin: 10px 0
}

.animais {
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%
}

.pessoas {
  background: #2980b9;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<table class='animais'>
  <tr>
    <td>Cachorro</td>
    <td>Gato</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peixe</td>
    <td>Zebra</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class='pessoas'>
  <tr>
    <td>Maria</td>
    <td>João</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jubiléia</td>
    <td>Cleoswaldo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Talvez seja de grande ajuda os links a seguir:
[HTML - W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp)
[CSS - W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp)